# Load country state city drop down from json

Tags: ajax, json

```
 *http://jsfiddle.net/Kishor_Walke/f78mY/*
```

I have tried to populate city according to the selected state but it not working propery. see the Fiddle. 
Plz help me.. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need two for loops

```
for(var i = 0; i < myJson.country.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<myJson.country[i].states.length;j++)
        {
           if(myJson.country[i].states[j].id == $(this).val())
               {
               //console.log($(this).val());
                   $('#city').html('<option value="000">-Select city-</option>');
                   $.each(myJson.country[i].states[j].cities, function (index, value) {

                   $("#city").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
                  });
              } 
        } 
    }
```

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/f78mY/1/